# sqlite3 item multiplies in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I created a python script that uploads items to a database. But the script gets executed multiple times and adds the same item to the database multiple times.

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('accounts.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
''')

cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO user(username,firstname,lastname,password)
VALUES('test_User','Bob','Smith','MrBob')
''')
db.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

It should output this

```
[(1, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob')]
```

But instead it outputs this

```
[(1, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (2, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (3, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (4, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (5, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (6, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (7, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (8, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (9, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (10, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (11, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob'), (12, 'test_User', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'MrBob')]
```

Comment: Presumably MySQL was a mis-tag here since this is SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, the problem is that, you've executed this script multiple times right?
Well, everytime you executed it, you inserted another record into the same db, because of `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. To fix this, just delete the sql database file `('account.db')` that was formed by the script, and re run it, you'll see that you will get the result you wanted!

The other solution is deleting the records that were present before executing the program, to get the same output everytime.

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect('accounts.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
userID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
firstname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL);
''')

# section added to remove preexisting records
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM user")

cursor.execute('''
INSERT INTO user(username,firstname,lastname,password)
VALUES('test_User','Bob','Smith','MrBob')
''')
db.commit()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user')
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: is their a way for me to keep the database file and have the script return the results that I want

Comment: yes there is, but you'll have to delete the records that are currently stored in it, since the duplicates form because you executed the same script multiple times, and it inserts the same record in the same database, deleting can be done with cursor.execute("DELETE FROM user")

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this whole thing I'm also currently in a competition for coding I have to make a program in 24 hours. Can you please add that function to my code and send it to me that'll help me a lot

Comment: i have added the section that removes the pre existing records into my answer, if this helped you, you can accept my answer as a solution!